# How to make a phone textfield clickable and able to call? (MudBlazor)

Tags: c#, html, razor, mudblazor

I have this line of code in MudBlazor:

```
<MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3">
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="DossierDetailViewModel.DossierDetail.DossierRepairer.Phone" Label="Telefono" ReadOnly="true" />
</MudItem>
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to make it able to be clicked and to open a call, just like how you do it in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

30/05/2021

Telephone input type was already implemented.
Check this out
https://github.com/Garderoben/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Enums/InputType.cs

So you can create an

`<MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Telephone" />`

**EDIT**

Sorry, I misread your question.
Not, is not possible at the moment to have an input type "tel", because the InputType enum doesn't have this option (see [implementation](https://github.com/Garderoben/MudBlazor/blob/22c6dfbf4b9c469804a712de146a665b93dbd407/src/MudBlazor/Enums/InputType.cs)). Feel free to open an issue in github

**OLD ANSWER**

If you want to have a readonly textfield that you manipulate not letting the user to insert data, then use MudField.

See this example
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOmbYfPrMIoGCVsG

```cs
<MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" @onclick=@HandleClick>
    <MudField T="string" Label="Telefono">@_value</MudField>
</MudItem>

@code{
    string   _value="my default value";
    void HandleClick(){
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}
```